# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis transform TextMessage to ObjectMessage

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I have a use case where I need to convert a message from one type to another (i.e. `TextMessage` -> `ObjectMessage`).

I found that when diverting between queues there is an option to transform the message. I have implemented the `Transformer` interface as instructed in the documentation.

```java
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.Message;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.transformer.Transformer;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
    
public class TypeTransformer implements Transformer {
    
    @Override
    public Message transform(Message message) {
        return message;
    }
}
```

But I am now beginning to realize that it might be impossible to convert from a `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.Message` to an `javax.jms.ObjectMessage`?

Is this right? That it cannot be done or is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should technically be possible to convert a `javax.jms.TextMessage` to a `javax.jms.ObjectMessage`, but it may be cumbersome. Here are some important things to note:

- `javax.jms.TextMessage`, `javax.jms.ObjectMessage`, and `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.Message` are all just *interfaces*. The `javax` version is what you use on the client and `Message` is what is used on the broker. The data for each type of message is stored differently in the underlying message implementation.
- The *class* for the Java object that you wish to put into the `ObjectMessage` will need to be on the broker's classpath. This isn't required under normal circumstances as the broker itself will never serialize or deserialize the object.
- You should really try to avoid `ObjectMessage` whenever possible. `ObjectMessage` objects depend on Java serialization to marshal and unmarshal their object payload. This process is generally considered unsafe (and slow!), because a malicious payload can exploit the host system. [Lots of CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=objectmessage) have been created for this. For this reason, most JMS providers force users to explicitly whitelist packages that can be exchanged using `ObjectMessage` messages. For example, here's the related [documentation for ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#controlling-jms-objectmessage-deserialization). There are a number of other issues with using JMS `ObjectMessage` not related to security that you should [read about](http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2012/07/27/on-jms-objectmessage-and-its-pitfalls/).

Granted you understand all that you should be able to convert the message using code something like this:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ICoreMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.Message;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.SimpleString;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.transformer.Transformer;

public class TypeTransformer implements Transformer {

   @Override
   public Message transform(Message message) {
      ICoreMessage coreMessage = message.toCore();
      try {
         // get the data from the TextMessage
         SimpleString mySimpleString = coreMessage.getBodyBuffer().readNullableSimpleString();
         if (mySimpleString == null) {
            // no text in the message so no transformation can be done
            return message;
         }
         String myString = mySimpleString.toString();

         // parse the data from the TextMessage and set it on the serializable object
         Serializable object = new MySerializable();         

         // turn serializable object into byte array and write it to the message
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
         oos.writeObject(object);
         oos.flush();
         byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
         coreMessage.getBodyBuffer().clear();
         coreMessage.getBodyBuffer().writeInt(data.length);
         coreMessage.getBodyBuffer().writeBytes(data);
         coreMessage.setType(Message.OBJECT_TYPE);

         return coreMessage;
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return message;
      }
   }
}
```