# How to perform data transformation in embedded ActiveMQ Artemis before journaling

Tags: activemq-artemis

I can do data transformation in incoming interceptors (before reaching ActiveMQ Artemis), but I want to do a transformation *after* reaching the server but before journaling.

Is there any interceptors where I can do transformation before jounaling?

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70954749/apache-activemq-artemis-transform-textmessage-to-objectmessage), and I did same by implementing `Transformer`, but I think transformation is done after journaling.

```xml
<remoting-incoming-interceptors>
    <class-name>org.example.CustomIncomingInterceptor</class-name>
</remoting-incoming-interceptors>

<diverts>
    <divert name="test-divert">
        <address>testQueue</address>
        <forwarding-address>testFwrd</forwarding-address>
        <transformer-class-name>org.example.MyCustomTransformer</transformer-class-name>
        <exclusive>false</exclusive>
    </divert>
</diverts>
```

Comment: How are you invoking your `Transformer` implementation?

Comment: Also, what kind of interceptor(s) are you using before the message even reaches the broker?

Comment: @JustinBertram , updated tags in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `divert` is configured to forward messages sent to `testQueue` to `testFwrd`. The `Transformer` will be invoked when the message is diverted and before it is routed `testFwrd`. If there are any queues on the `testFwrd` address then the transformed message will be persisted to disk (i.e. in the journal) at that time. Therefore, transformation will happen before journaling.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Is there any other best approach to do transformation with completely new code before journaling?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "completely new code before journaling"? Using a divert is really the _only_ way to execute a `Transformer` on an incoming message.

Comment: I heard about broker plugins today. I think I can achieve using broker plugins, and there are many options like beforeSend , beforeMessageRoute, etc. Now I am looking at which is the most suitable method to use transformer before journaling.
is divert better than broker plugins for my data transformation for the original message.

Comment: I would recommend a `divert` with a `Transformer` instead of a broker plugin.